# A simple question about Collatz Function,Why this is a unreachable code?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a new learner of python, when I try to write a Collatz function I find that pycharm shows me one line is unreachable. I wonder why the function can't run the code

```
def Collatz(numBer):
        if numBer%2 == 0:
            return numBer//2
        else:
            return 3*numBer+1
            print(numBer)       #this code is unreachale
print('Please input the number:')
numBer = int(input())
while numBer != 1:
    Collatz(numBer)
    print(Collatz(numBer))      #because the former code are unreachable,so I write this to print the results
    numBer = Collatz(numBer)
```

Answer (score 1):

All code within the same scope below a `return` statement is unreachable because the function will finish its execution there. In your case you are returning the result so there is no need to rerun the function again to print it. Just take it in a variable and use it:

```
def Collatz(numBer):
        if numBer%2 == 0:
            return numBer//2
        else:
            return 3*numBer+1

print('Please input the number:')
numBer = int(input())
while numBer != 1:
    numBer = Collatz(numBer)
    print(numBer)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very clear and beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Hello welcome to Stack Overflow!

The reason why the print is "unreachable" is because of the return before the print. `return` ends a control flow so any code after the return is disregarded. Basically, the control flow goes like this (based on your function):

"Is the numBer divisible by 2?"

"If yes, then give me the integer division of that number and 2"

"Otherwise, give me the 3*number + 1"

If you wanted to print the number before you return it, it would be best to store it first into a variable and then return that variable, like so:

```
def Collatz(numBer):
    if Collatz % 2 == 0:
       value = numBer // 2

    else:
       value = 3 * numBer + 1

    print(value)
    return value
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvement of the code, it shows me a new way to achieve it.